# JavaScript convert string into Date with format (dd mmm yyyy) i.e. 01 Jun 2012

Tags: javascript, date, date-formatting

I am getting a string variable having date in format `6/1/2012`, I want to convert it into `01 Jun 2012` .
**[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K5fn2/2/)**

Code I tried:

```
var t_sdate="6/1/2012";                  
var sptdate = String(t_sdate).split("/");
var myMonth = sptdate[0];
var myDay = sptdate[1];
var myYear = sptdate[2];
var combineDatestr = myYear + "/" + myMonth + "/" + myDay;

var dt = new Date(combineDatestr);
var formatedDate= dt.format("dd mmm yyyy")
alert(formatedDate);
```

Getting output as `01 000 2012`, required as `01 Jun 2012`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Date] has no method 'format'  was the error logged in console. The code you have will work if you include dateformat-js plugin in your code.

Comment: am not using any external js file, is it possible to do it without using any external  file

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: did u use this http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format ? u sure u dwonloaded the date.format.js file and set it up properly before u started coding?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getFormattedDate(input) {
    var pattern = /(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)$/;
    var result = input.replace(pattern,function(match,p1,p2,p3){
        var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
        return (p2<10?"0"+p2:p2) + " " + months[(p1-1)] + " " + p3;
    });

    alert(result);
}

getFormattedDate("6/1/2013");
```

[Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/43hbB/315/)

Comment: Perfect Solution, ultimate without adding `external js`

Comment: is there any way to print day name along with same code?

Comment: Perfect Solution

Answer (score 2):

Since other users already  mentioned  that  `"format"` is not a standard method of Date object. You can do it without using any format method (even if there exist any)

```
var t_sdate = "6/1/2012";
var sptdate = String(t_sdate).split("/");
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
var myMonth = sptdate[0];
var myDay = sptdate[1];
var myYear = sptdate[2];
var combineDatestr = myDay + " " + months[myMonth - 1] + " " + myYear;

alert(combineDatestr);
```

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fdf4o7om/)

Answer (score 1):

```
return $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-M-yy', new Date(dateVal)); //01-Dec-2014
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. In general, if the tags don't include `jquery` (or another library), the answers should refrain from using libraries to solve the problem (or they can suggest that using a library would be easier). Here, you just assume the OP is using jQueryUI; the answer would have been more useful had you suggested that jQueryUI has this cool functionality, but no library answers are still preferred (especially given OP's question comment). Also take a look at Stack Overflow formatting help: indent four characters for code blocks (or put in backticks for inline code).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use javascript Intl
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat

The following example will show something like `Nov 02, 2017`

`console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-EN', { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' }).format(new Date()));`

Milton.-

Answer (score -1):

"format" is not a standard method of Date object

Answer (score -4):

```
dt.format("dd MMM yyyy")
```

Use capital letters.

Comment: As guy777 correctly points out, standard JavaScript does not have a `format` function.