# Convert yyyymmdd to dd-mmm-yyyy

Tags: javascript

I have a date in the format yyyymmdd. 
Ex:  20141004

What I need to do is to convert it like dd-mmm-yyyy. 
Ex: 4 Oct 2014

There is a similar question here: [JavaScript convert string into Date with format (dd mmm yyyy) i.e. 01 Jun 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17445585/javascript-convert-string-into-date-with-format-dd-mmm-yyyy-i-e-01-jun-2012)

The difference is that I have no "/" character to split by.

Another limitation is that I cannot use any external library, as this code is used inside another tool, so **I need native JS**.

Comment: Use a date/time library.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [momentjs](http://momentjs.com) for things like this.

Comment: The question and answer is not the same, as you can se I have no "/" in my date string, so I cannot split it.

Comment: this is a good JQuery Lib: https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat

Comment: I cannot use any external library, as this code is used inside another tool, so **I need native JS**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this:

```js
var date = "20141004";
var y = date.substring(0, 4);
var m = parseInt(date.substring(4, 6), 10);
var d = date.substring(6, 8);

var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

mm = months[m - 1];

document.write(d + " " + mm + " " + y);
```